# Unity. RootMotion - вопрос про анимации и движение

Tags: unity3d

уважаемые друзья. У меня есть единственное древо смешивания анимаций, и вот беда. Точнее несколько:

1. При нажатии вперед, влево, вправо, назад, вперед-вправо и вперед-влево всё хорошо, персонаж стоит на месте (допустим, что пока что это - хорошо). Но когда жму назад+право или назад+влево - моделька персонажа начинает сдвигаться туда, куда идёт, а центр модельки остается в центре экрана. В итоге слежение за курсором моделькой сбивается и она начинает крутить по огромному радиусу. Почему модель сдвигается?

[image: Blending Tree]

2. Почему не работает движение? Вроде, делал по туториалу. Персонаж проигрывает анимации правильно, но на месте. Никуда не двигается.

Вот код движения. PlayerController стандартный.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ControlPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator _anim;
    public CharacterController charControl;

    private float vertical;
    private float horizontal;

    [Header("Поворот:")]
    public Transform bodyTransform; 
    public float smooth = 3;
    public bool useSmooth;

    private Vector3 rootMotion;
    
    void Start()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        charControl = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        _anim.SetFloat("Vertical", vertical);
        _anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", horizontal);

        OnGround();
        Rotation();
    }

    void OnAnimatorMove()
    {
        rootMotion += _anim.deltaPosition;
    }

    void OnGround()
    {
        charControl.Move(rootMotion);
        rootMotion = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void Rotation() 
    {
        Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.y)) - _anim.deltaPosition;
        lookPos.y = 0; 

        if(useSmooth)
        {
            Quaternion playerRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
            bodyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(bodyTransform.rotation, playerRotation, smooth * Time.fixedDeltaTime); 
            
        }
        else
        {
            bodyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
            
        }
    }
}
```